# Livecode text file not showing contents

Tags: livecode

I have a system for a highscore, which asks you to enter your name, and it will save your score into a text file. This text file will then be opened again when the score button is pressed, showing all the high scores.
Right now, when the score button is pressed, it only answers with a blank window.
The file Scores.txt does have the scores all saved.
Here is the text for the scores button:

```
on mouseUp
   put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/Scores.txt" into myFile
   set itemDelimiter to tab
   put  url ("file:" & myFile)    into    x
   sort lines of x numeric descending by item 2 of each
   answer x
end mouseUp
```

Here is the code which saves the scores to scores.txt:

```
on stopGame
   put false into gameisRunning
   set the bottom of btn "bird" to 225
   set the angle of image "Bird" of stack "graphics" to 0
   ask "What is your name?"
   if it is not empty then
      put it into theName
      put specialFolderPath("Documents") & "Scores.txt" into myFile
      put URL("file:" & myFile) into highScores
      put theName & tab & field "score" & return after highScores
      put highScores into URL ( "File:" & myFile)
   end if
end stopGame
```

Answer (score 1):

In the stopGame you have missed the slash "/" it should be the same as you had in the mouseUp:

```
put specialFolderPath("Documents") & "/Scores.txt" into myFile
```

Good Luck!